# Time sheets signed the day ahead

Tags: salary

Is it fraud for my supervisor to ask me to sign my time sheet a day ahead so she could send it in on the day they are supposed to be submitted to the pay office?

Comment: What makes you think this is fraud? This is how it works everywhere.

Comment: Is the issue the signing date? For example, if the time sheet is due on the 30th, and today is the 29th, then I would just write "29 June 2015 <Signature>".

Comment: I've never run across this before in all my years of doing timesheets.  Sounds very sketchy.

Comment: Is there a correction process if you deviate from what you 'commit' to on this timesheet? If so, I see this as a huge timesaver. If there isn't, then it's a big bus waiting to throw people under it.

Comment: @Jack To be fair, being how something works everywhere doesn't mean it's not fraud. I don't think it's necessarily fraud but it could be a part of a fraudulent process depending on how their timekeeping system works. IMHO, OP's company's pay system is whack. They have conflicting requirements and should shift the pay schedule to allow time sheets to be completed after work is completed.

Comment: It's absolutely not fraud *provided* the company has procedures that are being followed for accounting for the hours he worked *if there is a variance* that is acceptable to both employee and employer (e.g. employee managed flex time, company managed comp days, a direct pay adjustment to account for the variance, etc), and time he did not work is not being billed to clients.  Also, there is zero fraud if your time matches up as expected. Only exception is company policy: talk to HR to see if policy states you can only sign for completed time.

Comment: This can be commonly done before a period where a majority of people are going to be taking time off. For example, in the US, almost everyone gets July 3rd (Friday) off this year. It is not uncommon for employees to be asked to submit their time sheets on Thursday. Or, for example, if you are going to take all of "next" week off, our HR department wants you to submit your time sheet ahead of time.

Comment: "Time sheet" is a pretty vague term these days. It can mean many different things at many different companies and have many different levels of 'authenticity'. Some places use it as a contract almost and you are entirely expected to have full responsibility for accurate tracking to peg it against your pay. Other places use it as merely a data point that can be easily manipulated week to week to make the office politics work and doesn't necessarily have any bearing on reality. As such, it all depends...

Answer (score 57):

**Short answer:** If they are the hours that you intend to work *and do work*, it is absolutely not fraud.

It's very common for this to happen.  I've done it at least a dozen times in my career.  Sometimes you'll be working off site, or for some reason unable to get a timesheet signed on the day they're normally submitted.

If for some reason your actual hours vary from the timesheet hours you submitted, you can just notify them of a correction and if necessary any adjustments to pay.

Comment: My personal anecdote which supports this answer: where I work I am _required_ to submit time the day before the end of the pay period. If there are any variances on the final day (e.g. I call in sick), we amend it the following week.

Comment: @Snowman I too have worked under that reporting paradigm.

Comment: +1 - another anecodote: I deal with software that manages literally thousands of timesheets for dozens of companies, and I can tell you that signing off a timesheet before the end of the pay period is *very* normal, and any adjustments are made in the following pay period.

Answer (score 52):

It's common enough that even Scott Adams has covered it...

[image: Dilbert Timesheets]

I've always felt a bit sketchy about doing it myself, but usually there are ways of correcting projected mistakes later (say undercharging the same day the following week, or an actual correction to the timesheet etc).

Comment: That comic is me every week.

Comment: Ha! Yes, in IT I've found time sheets really have nothing to do with time worked and everything to do with making magic numbers match the magic estimates and arbitrary time lines.

Answer (score 7):

If the supervisor gets a bonus for collecting and delivering all time sheets quickly at the end of the day, and gets his bonus by delivering time sheets that were filled out before you actually did the work, lying about this to his boss, yes.

If you are forced to work an hour longer and the supervisor denies payment because that hour is not on your time sheet, yes.

If you don't arrive at work because of an accident, and the supervisor still charges a customer for the eight hours on your time sheet, yes.

As long as all the data on the time sheet is considered as preliminary and is adjusted to reality when necessary, it's fine.

Answer (score 5):

The company has to have in place procedures for how to address changes between the time you sign, and the end of the pay period. If they are following the procedures it is not fraud.

If they are billing customers for your time the customers will insist that either time cards can only be submitted after the end of the pay period, or that there are documented procedures for addressing these changes. They will want to be able to see not only the final time card, but the list of changes and the reason for those changes.

Besides being able to bill correctly, which does allow them to keep customers, the employee also wants to have these adjustment procedures to protect their vacation. For example if you think you will be on leave the last day, but you are called in for an emergency and have to put in 12 hours of work: you want to be paid for that time not charged 8 hours of leave.

There should be time card procedures documented, and you should receive training on those procedures. Many companies require annual retraining to reenforce those procedures.